# Catching exceptions in a render call from a rails helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeview

This is for a rails 4.0.2 application running ruby 2.0.0-p353.

I have a helper that has the following method

```
def render_feed_row(activity_item)
  begin
    if activity_item.type == "comment"
      render "newsfeed/comment", :item => activity_item
    elsif activity_item.type == "post"
      render "newsfeed/post", :item => activity_item
    else
      raise NameError
    end
  rescue NameError => e # note: NoMethodError is a subclass of NameError
    render "newsfeed/other", :item => activity_item
  end
end
```

But if a `NoMethodError` is raised in the `newsfeed/post` partial, it is not caught in this helper. Why is that? It don't render `newsfeed/other`, it actually raises an exception.

Comment: Strangely, I've catched `NoMethodError` when raising `NameError` exception. Please show us `NoMethodError.superclass` output in the environment

Comment: Interesting ... I'm getting "NoMethodError in Users::Profile#transactions_log" because of "undefined method `display_name' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: I think your should specify something like `rescue NameError, NoMethodError => e`? it'll allow catching `NoMethodError` in a current namespace.

Comment: Good idea. I just tried that, but it didn't work :(

Comment: And just `rescue NoMethodError` placed in additional line?

Comment: Since I have no rails 4, I can only say that you should perform, `grep ` rails for definition of the `def NoMethodError` like `grep NoMethodError /path/to/gems/* -r|grep ".rb:"`, then open found files on-by-one, and see the module in where the class is defined. And put trap in full form like "rescue Module::NoMethodError". If the `NoMethodError` is defined at top-level. There is workaround way to trap. just trap all exception `rescue Exception => e` then use `e.to_s =~ /NoMethodError/` to select it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just checked with a simplified version of your code, and it worked correctly.

```
def render_feed_row
  raise NoMethodError
rescue NameError
  puts "kaboom"
end

render_feed_row
# => kaboom
```

However, please note it's a very bad practice to use exceptions for control flow in such way. Moreover, if you really want to use exceptions, you should create your own classes, not use `NoMethodError` or `NameError` that have specific meanings in Ruby programs.

Here's a more clean version of your method

```
def render_feed_row(activity_item)
  case (type = activity_item.type)
  when "comment", "post"
    render "newsfeed/#{type}", item: activity_item
  else
    render "newsfeed/other", item: activity_item
  end
end
```

Or a more concise version

```
def render_feed_row(activity_item)
  name = case activity_item.type
  when "comment", "post"
    activity_item.type
  else
    "other"
  end
  render "newsfeed/#{name}", item: activity_item
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Using exceptions for control flow is slow. Why not just:

```
def render_feed_row(activity_item)
  partial = ['comment', 'post'].include?(activity_item.type) ? 
                                                    activity_item.type : 'other'

  render "newsfeed/#{partial}", :item => activity_item
end
```